# How to get marker position after dragging in vue2-google-map?

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

I am using the vue2-google-map library to display a map with a marker.

```
<gmap-map ref="mymap" :center="mapStartLocation" :zoom="17" style="width: 100%; height: 300px">
    <gmap-marker v-on:change="updateCoordinates()" :position="mapStartLocation" :draggable="true" @closeclick="updateCoordinates()"/>
</gmap-map>
```

This works and puts the marker on the coordinates of mapStartLocation

**How do I  get the new coordinates after the user draggs the marker on the map?**

I tried with a @closeClick and v-on:change but neither registers. Even if they would, the question of how to get the new coordinate values remains.

Any pointers on how to operate with this library. 
Nothing in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found `@drag` to be the best solution. However, the event is emitted while the user is dragging, not only after, to which `@dragend` should work [according to source-code](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/vue2/src/components/marker.js), but for some reason doesn't in my case.

```
<template>
    <gmap-map ref="mymap" :center="mapStartLocation" :zoom="17" style="width: 100%; height: 300px">
        <gmap-marker :position="mapStartLocation" :draggable="true" @drag="updateCoordinates" />
    </gmap-map>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            coordinates: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateCoordinates(location) {
            this.coordinates = {
                lat: location.latLng.lat(),
                lng: location.latLng.lng(),
            };
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. How do you pass the coordinate values with this method to the updateCoordinates() method?

Comment: Location is passed as parameter - see updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just faced same situation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for pointing that out, it's nowhere documented though, how can I find that event in the future by myself?

Comment: There is some documentation here, but could use some work: https://github.com/Jeson-gk/vue2-google-maps/blob/master/API.md

Answer (score 8):

So, You can add Event on stop drag

```
<GmapMarker
   :position="jdata.geo"
   :clickable="true"
   :draggable="true"
   @dragend="gMapFunc($event.latLng)"
 </GmapMarker>
```

////////////////////////

```
 methods: {
      //set after merker end drag
      gMapFunc(evnt) {
        this.jdata = {"geo": {"lat":evnt.lat(), "lng":evnt.lng()}};
      },
```